# Best way to read all CSV files from two folders with different dates (LOOP)

Tags: r

Is there an easy way or loop that would allow me to read all CSVs from two folders same files from different dates? The folders will have identical datasets from different dates. The goal is to be able to create queries from these datasets and be able to identify issues that have occurred over time. I'd like to rename the CSVs with an identifier such as  old/new.

Example data:  FILEA.CSV FILEB.CSV FILEC.CSV

Name of file read into R:  FILEA_old, FILEA_new, FILEB_old, FILEB_new, FILEC_old, FILEC_new

I've very early in the process of programming this. I am already getting errors here:

```
Date<-c("17JUL2021", "18AUG2021") 
for (i in Date) {
files <- list.files(path = paste0("~datapath",Date,"//csv//", pattern = '.csv$', full.names = F))}
```

I need help with the loop to rename the files based on if the file is old or new:

```
names <- str_replace(files,".csv","_old")
```

then I read in all the files into R:

```
for(i in names){
      
  filepath <- file.path(paste(i,".csv",sep=""))
  assign(i, read.csv(filepath))
        
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If all csv files are the same (or similar) format, rather than `assign` each csv file to a different object, I would recommend combing them all into a single object, and keeping the name of the file as an identifier in a separate column.

We can use `map()` as an alternative to a `for` loop, which creates a list of all outputs, which can be combined using `bind_rows`.

Note how I pipe the names of all files from `list.files` into map, but you can keep it as a separate `files` object if you prefer. Using `recursive = TRUE` means `list.files` looks inside all folders in your path, and `full.names = TRUE` returns the full path of each file.

In this example I have a parent folder `csv files`, and then 2 subfolders `folder_1` and `folder_2`, each of which contains `file_1.csv`, `file_2.csv` and `file_3.csv`.

```
# first we list all the files
list.files(path = 'csv files', full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE) %>% 
  
  # then we map() over this function, which reads a csv and then makes a column with the files name
  map(function(x){
    read_csv(x) %>% 
      mutate(
        file = x
      )
  }
    ) %>% 
  
  # join all csvs together
  bind_rows %>% 
  
  # and save it as 'my_data'
  {. ->> my_data} 

my_data

# A tibble: 18 x 2
    data file                         
   <dbl> <chr>                        
 1     1 csv files/folder_1/file_1.csv
 2     2 csv files/folder_1/file_1.csv
 3     3 csv files/folder_1/file_1.csv
 4     1 csv files/folder_1/file_2.csv
 5     2 csv files/folder_1/file_2.csv
 6     3 csv files/folder_1/file_2.csv
 7     1 csv files/folder_1/file_3.csv
 8     2 csv files/folder_1/file_3.csv
 9     3 csv files/folder_1/file_3.csv
10     1 csv files/folder_2/file_1.csv
11     2 csv files/folder_2/file_1.csv
12     3 csv files/folder_2/file_1.csv
13     1 csv files/folder_2/file_2.csv
14     2 csv files/folder_2/file_2.csv
15     3 csv files/folder_2/file_2.csv
16     1 csv files/folder_2/file_3.csv
17     2 csv files/folder_2/file_3.csv
18     3 csv files/folder_2/file_3.csv
```

If you then want to change the names of the files from `_new` to `_old` or whatever you like, I would suggest making a new column, and populate it based on the name of the filepath. In this example, I could call all files from `folder_1` the 'old' files.

```
my_data %>% 
  mutate(
    age = ifelse(str_detect(file, 'folder_1'), 'old', 'new')
  )

# A tibble: 18 x 3
    data file                          age  
   <dbl> <chr>                         <chr>
 1     1 csv files/folder_1/file_1.csv old  
 2     2 csv files/folder_1/file_1.csv old  
 3     3 csv files/folder_1/file_1.csv old  
 4     1 csv files/folder_1/file_2.csv old  
 5     2 csv files/folder_1/file_2.csv old  
 6     3 csv files/folder_1/file_2.csv old  
 7     1 csv files/folder_1/file_3.csv old  
 8     2 csv files/folder_1/file_3.csv old  
 9     3 csv files/folder_1/file_3.csv old  
10     1 csv files/folder_2/file_1.csv new  
11     2 csv files/folder_2/file_1.csv new  
12     3 csv files/folder_2/file_1.csv new  
13     1 csv files/folder_2/file_2.csv new  
14     2 csv files/folder_2/file_2.csv new  
15     3 csv files/folder_2/file_2.csv new  
16     1 csv files/folder_2/file_3.csv new  
17     2 csv files/folder_2/file_3.csv new  
18     3 csv files/folder_2/file_3.csv new
```

I would advise against modifying the file column, as it can be handy for tracing back issues and troubleshooting the data down the track, if you need to check your original csv files.

Comment: thanks! i tried this it isn't feasible. The parent folder contains hundreds of folders and within each there are different types of datasets within folders like csv and sas. It would require much memory and processing power to read all the files. I need a program that would allow me to change just the dates of the path so I'm able to read the two exact datasets I need to compare.  Example path "~data/17JUL2021/csv/filename.csv"

Comment: Could you identify only the files you need using a pattern inside `list.files`, such as `'.csv'` or the `Date` values in your example? Or, could you save the output of `list.files` as a column in a `tibble`. Then, using `filter` among other functions, keep a vector of only the filenames you want to import? I have used the example in my answer to import and combine ~300-400 excel files, so it can work for many files.